# how to create javascript function that takes inputs from multiple functions

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to add a function to this code that will display the difference between the values calculated by the other two currently implemented functions but I'm unsure how to implement it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<div>
<header>
</header>
<main>
    <p>Your current daily goal is:<span id="UserGoal"></span></p>
    <br>
    <p>Your current calories eaten for the day:<span id="EatenCalories">0</span></p>
    <br>
    <p>Remaining calories for today:<span id="RemainingCalories"></span></p>
    <label for="Goal">Please enter your daily Goal</label>
    <input type="number" id="Goal" name="Goal">
    <input type="submit" onclick="updateGoal();"/>
    <br>
    <input type="number" id="addCalories" name"addCalories">
    <input type="button" value="Update Calories" onclick="addCalories();"/>
</main>
<script>
    function updateGoal(){
        this.UserGoal = document.getElementById("Goal").value;
        document.getElementById("UserGoal").innerHTML = this.UserGoal;
    }
    function addCalories(){
    if (this.EatenCalories = ''){ //made 1 = sign, made check ''
    this.EatenCalories = document.getElementById("addCalories").value;
    document.getElementById("EatenCalories").innerHTML = this.EatenCalories;
    }
    else{
    this.EatenCalories = document.getElementById("EatenCalories").innerText;
    parseFloat(EatenCalories);
    this.Calories=document.getElementById("addCalories").value;
    this.Result=parseFloat(this.Calories)+parseFloat(this.EatenCalories);
    document.getElementById("EatenCalories").innerHTML = this.Result;
    }
    }
</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: make each of your functions return the value that they're calculating first, and then call them both from your new function and do your math on the two results.

Answer (score 0):

Both the functions store their results in HTML elements by updating their innerHTML

Your new function can use these values to calculate the difference and put the result into another HTML element’s innerHTML to display it.

For example,

```
<div id=“difference”></div>

function calcDifference() {
  document.getElementById("difference").innerHTML = document.getElementById("EatenCalories").innerHTML - document.getElementById("UserGoal").innerHTML;
}
```